# Can we merge two .NSF file in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have made my own .NSF file from **mail85.ntf** and i have added my own stuff in this new nsf file. What actually it does is that it calls a java agent when a action button (places near 'send' ) is pressed.Now my question is:

1. How can I merge this NSF file with the existing mail.nsf file. Such that I can use the feature of my NSF file along with the existing feature of NSF file. Is that possible in lotus notes ?

My goal is to integrate my own NSF file with the existing NSF file without loosing current and new features.

Answer (score 3):

If your "own stuff" involves design changes then you give your DB a template name and refresh the other DB from your DB using DESIGN-REFRESH (not DESIGN-REPLACE). The design changes will then be in both databases.

If your "own stuff" has to do with documents then you can use copy/paste to move the ones you want from one DB to the other. If there a lot of them, then LotusScript NotesDatabase.AllDocument.CopyToDatabase(tragetDB) will move them with less manual action.

Comment: as per your first suggestion when i am doing DESIGN-REFRESH on any selected NSF i am only getting the a dialog box asking 'With design from server' and in the drop down i only see 'Local'. I am not getting the target NSF file from which i have to update the selected NSF. I have also updated my question for more clarification. I am not using any domino server right now my notes client is configured for gmail.

Comment: You can do design refresh locally. The Master Template name of the source database and Inherit design from Master Template name of the target database need to be the same. The refresh process will then find the source database. This is done because it is possible to have design elements come form a variety of master templates.

Comment: When i refresh my form it remove all the element that i had added and reset back to as per master template. how can i protect my element from replacing when i refresh it?

Comment: There are two settings for each design element available in the Properties in Domino designer. On the "Design" tab you can slecte "Prohibit design refresh/replace to modify" which does exactly what you ask. You can also set the value in "Inherit from the design template" to some other value. This allows you to keep your customized elements in one source template nsf while the core ones are in another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your version of the mail BUT KEEP your **new** stuffs:

- indicate for each design (of your version of the mail) "prohibit design refresh or replace to modify"

This will allow you to refresh design without loosing your changes.

Please note that if the element is not a new one but a modified one flagging prohibit design... will also disallow the refresh BUT you will have to merge the changes **in this** element, if in the future, the template changes **this** element.

NB if you need to do that on many DB (I mean many db have the SAME changes you've done) I suggest copy the new/changed elements in a blank DB. This DB has to be a new master template. Then copy all the elements of this new DB. When pasting in the target mails, Designer will ask if "would you like these (agent/form...) to be automatically updated when ...." simply answer yes the pasted elements will flaged has inheriting from your new template.

hope it's clear

Comment: `prohibit design refresh or replace to modify` i am not getting this option anywhere.